# getting difftime of a data set

Tags: r

i have a question according to diff or difftime.

```
Equip <- c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003)
Notif <- c(321,322,322,319,319,345,495,495,495,441,441,441,471,471)
Job <- c("01.01.2011","05.01.2011","05.01.2011","05.01.2011","05.01.2011",
"15.01.2011","23.03.2011","23.03.2011","23.03.2011","27.03.2011","27.03.2011",
"27.03.2011","29.03.2011",
"29.03.2011")
Job <- as.Date(Job,format="%d. %m. %Y")
df <- data.frame(Equip,Notif,Job)
```

I want to have a new column in the data.frame where the time difference [in days] should be.

The CONDITIONS to calculate the time difference are following:
What i want to do now is, if the  Equipnumber is the same, but the Notifnumber is different, i want to have the the time difference(Jobdate)

the output should be like this:

```
df$dd <- c(0,4,4,0,0,10,0,0,0,4,4,4,2,2)
```

( For the first Notifnumber in a Equipnumber, dd is 0 because it is the first visit)

Hopefully you can help me i try do it, but i can not do it like i want to have.

I can only use the standard R programm without any package...

According to the given link, i create following example which also does not work:

Maybe you can help me:

```
Equips <- c(10006250,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,
10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006252,10006777)
Notifs <- c(306863771,306862774,306862774,306862774,306933440,
306933440,306998451,306998451,307024311,307024311,
307024311,307024311,307033136,307033136,307128754,307158697)
Jobs <- c("25.01.2011","23.06.2011","23.06.2011","23.06.2011","28.06.2011",
"28.06.2011","02.07.2011","02.07.2011","03.09.2011","03.09.2011",
"03.09.2011","03.09.2011","05.09.2011","05.09.2011","02.11.2011","05.05.2011")
Comps <- c("Service Boiler","General Boiler Components","Ignition and Flame Detection",
"Service Boiler!!!","Electrical Components","Gas Train Assembly",
"Control Box"," Ignition and Flame Detection","CH Components Active",
"CH Components Passive","CH Components Passive","DHW Components",
"DHW Components","Internal Pipeworks and Connections","not grouped in WCC",
"Service Boiler")
Category <- c("service_repair","service_repair","service_repair",
"service_repair","repair","repair","repair","repair","repair","repair",
"repair","repair","repair","repair","repair","service_repair")
Job <- as.Date(Job,format="%d. %m. %Y")
df <- data.frame(Equips,Notifs,Jobs,Comps,Category)
```

I really do not know why it does'nt work with this, but with the data from the first post,
maybe you are able to help me.

Comment: What do you mean about `if the Equipnumber is the same, but the Notifnumber is different`? Your desired output vector is the same length as your input vectors (14), so it's not like you're computing it for only certain values. What are you supposed to do if the Equipnumber *isn't* the same, or the Notifnumber *isn't*? How did you come up with the third number in your output (4) since the date is the same for those two values?

Comment: Equips is a thing which should repaired. Notif is a number for a visit. So i just want to compare different visits by one Equip....If Equip is not the same, so its the first time with a new Equip. for this dd is 0!(Because first visit) If the Equip is in the following line the same, but Notif is different, then dd(its like the second visit). If its the same Notif give same dd (because it's the same visit, so dd is the same like the line before) if Equip is the same again and Notif is different, then new dd(new visit). If Equip is differrent, start again with 0.(because new thing)

Comment: Do notifs ever span multiple days?

Comment: No, one Notif just for one day. Maybe it looks unclear to you because somethimes therre are the same lines (like the second 4 or the second 2 etc. but it's just a part of the dataset. There are some other columns with more information in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is bit long and perhaps convoluted answer using base packages. Someone with better knowledge of `plyr` may be able to give more elegant solution.

```
> df
   Equip Notif        Job
1   1001   321 2011-01-01
2   1001   322 2011-01-05
3   1001   322 2011-01-05
4   1002   319 2011-01-05
5   1002   319 2011-01-05
6   1002   345 2011-01-15
7   1003   495 2011-03-23
8   1003   495 2011-03-23
9   1003   495 2011-03-23
10  1003   441 2011-03-27
11  1003   441 2011-03-27
12  1003   441 2011-03-27
13  1003   471 2011-03-29
14  1003   471 2011-03-29
```

First get `diff` in dates without any condition

```
> df$diff <- c(0,diff(df$Job))
> df
   Equip Notif        Job diff
1   1001   321 2011-01-01    0
2   1001   322 2011-01-05    4
3   1001   322 2011-01-05    0
4   1002   319 2011-01-05    0
5   1002   319 2011-01-05    0
6   1002   345 2011-01-15   10
7   1003   495 2011-03-23   67
8   1003   495 2011-03-23    0
9   1003   495 2011-03-23    0
10  1003   441 2011-03-27    4
11  1003   441 2011-03-27    0
12  1003   441 2011-03-27    0
13  1003   471 2011-03-29    2
14  1003   471 2011-03-29    0
```

Create new column `diff1` which is `1` is your condition is true and `0` if false

```
> df$diff1 <- c(0, ifelse(diff(df$Equip) == 0 & diff(df$Notif) != 0, 1, 0))
> df
   Equip Notif        Job diff diff1
1   1001   321 2011-01-01    0     0
2   1001   322 2011-01-05    4     1
3   1001   322 2011-01-05    0     0
4   1002   319 2011-01-05    0     0
5   1002   319 2011-01-05    0     0
6   1002   345 2011-01-15   10     1
7   1003   495 2011-03-23   67     0
8   1003   495 2011-03-23    0     0
9   1003   495 2011-03-23    0     0
10  1003   441 2011-03-27    4     1
11  1003   441 2011-03-27    0     0
12  1003   441 2011-03-27    0     0
13  1003   471 2011-03-29    2     1
14  1003   471 2011-03-29    0     0
```

Multiply the results to get value of diff column only when condition is true

```
> df$diff <- df$diff * df$diff1
> df$diff1 <- NULL
> df
   Equip Notif        Job diff
1   1001   321 2011-01-01    0
2   1001   322 2011-01-05    4
3   1001   322 2011-01-05    0
4   1002   319 2011-01-05    0
5   1002   319 2011-01-05    0
6   1002   345 2011-01-15   10
7   1003   495 2011-03-23    0
8   1003   495 2011-03-23    0
9   1003   495 2011-03-23    0
10  1003   441 2011-03-27    4
11  1003   441 2011-03-27    0
12  1003   441 2011-03-27    0
13  1003   471 2011-03-29    2
14  1003   471 2011-03-29    0
```

Merge the data with itself to repeat values if the readings are repeated. (Although this step may need to be changed if you have other columns in the dataset)

```
> res <- merge(df[,1:3], df[df$diff!=0,], all.x=T)
> res
   Equip Notif        Job diff
1   1001   321 2011-01-01   NA
2   1001   322 2011-01-05    4
3   1001   322 2011-01-05    4
4   1002   319 2011-01-05   NA
5   1002   319 2011-01-05   NA
6   1002   345 2011-01-15   10
7   1003   441 2011-03-27    4
8   1003   441 2011-03-27    4
9   1003   441 2011-03-27    4
10  1003   471 2011-03-29    2
11  1003   471 2011-03-29    2
12  1003   495 2011-03-23   NA
13  1003   495 2011-03-23   NA
14  1003   495 2011-03-23   NA
```

Replace NAs with 0

```
> res[is.na(res)] <- 0
> res
   Equip Notif        Job diff
1   1001   321 2011-01-01    0
2   1001   322 2011-01-05    4
3   1001   322 2011-01-05    4
4   1002   319 2011-01-05    0
5   1002   319 2011-01-05    0
6   1002   345 2011-01-15   10
7   1003   441 2011-03-27    4
8   1003   441 2011-03-27    4
9   1003   441 2011-03-27    4
10  1003   471 2011-03-29    2
11  1003   471 2011-03-29    2
12  1003   495 2011-03-23    0
13  1003   495 2011-03-23    0
14  1003   495 2011-03-23    0
```

For the second example data with more columns, replace 2 steps with

```
res <- merge(df[,c('Equip', 'Notif', 'Job', 'Comps', 'Category')], df[ df$diff !=0    ,c('Equip', 'Notif', 'Job', 'diff')], all.x=T)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
      Equip     Notif        Job                              Comps       Category diff
1  10006250 306863771 2011-01-25                     Service Boiler service_repair    0
2  10006252 306862774 2011-06-23          General Boiler Components service_repair    0
3  10006252 306862774 2011-06-23       Ignition and Flame Detection service_repair    0
4  10006252 306862774 2011-06-23                  Service Boiler!!! service_repair    0
5  10006252 306933440 2011-06-28              Electrical Components         repair    5
6  10006252 306933440 2011-06-28                 Gas Train Assembly         repair    5
7  10006252 306998451 2011-07-02                        Control Box         repair    4
8  10006252 306998451 2011-07-02       Ignition and Flame Detection         repair    4
9  10006252 307024311 2011-09-03               CH Components Active         repair   63
10 10006252 307024311 2011-09-03              CH Components Passive         repair   63
11 10006252 307024311 2011-09-03              CH Components Passive         repair   63
12 10006252 307024311 2011-09-03                     DHW Components         repair   63
13 10006252 307033136 2011-09-05                     DHW Components         repair    2
14 10006252 307033136 2011-09-05 Internal Pipeworks and Connections         repair    2
15 10006252 307128754 2011-11-02                 not grouped in WCC         repair   58
16 10006777 307158697 2011-05-05                     Service Boiler service_repair    0
```

Comment: Hey This look as a good answer, because i just want to do with R and witout any package.... but if you look to your output, it is not that one which i want to have. First they are unsortet, the second thing is if i tested on my original data it doesn't work... hmm maybe you have goot another idea?

Comment: this link show what i mean:[link] http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2483/datumr.jpg[/link]   for example the first 4 should also stand in the next linke because its the same visit (same Equips and same Notifs) got what i mean ?

Comment: if you give complete example dataset, perhaps I can amend my answer to fit it.

Comment: Maybe do you have an answer for it?